# Input um abaixo do outro

Tags: html, css, css3

Estou fazendo um código `HTML`.

Tenho alguns inputs criados porém eles estão ficando um do lado do outro como se tivesse um float neles, só que eu não quero assim.

Quero que fique um abaixo do outro, tem uma função no `CSS` que faz isso?

Eu sei que com o `<br>` eu consigo fazer, porém queria saber como faz no `CSS`.

Answer (score 5):

Existem várias maneiras de fazer isso pelo CSS, mas o importante é vc saber que o `input` é um elemento do tipo `inline`, na verdade `inline-block`, ou seja, ele fica em linha, pois só ocupa o espaço dele mesmo, assim como `labels`, `spans`, etc.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Mas como resolver isso só com CSS?**

Uma das formas de colocar um `input` por linha é dando a ele o `display:block`, assim ele ocupa 100% da largura da tela, e o próximo `input` só viria a baixo dele, na "linha de baixo".

```css
input {
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<input type="text">
<input type="text">
<input type="text">
```

Comment: Hugo eu tentei fazer isso só que os inputs saem do alinhamento. Estou utilizando `text-align: center;` no `<form>`, mas ao colocar `block` nos inputs eles não ficam mais centralizados.

Comment: @JeanExtreme002 fala Jean, cada depois que vc muda ele para display: block ele passa a aceitar alguns atributos do `box model block`, então com um simples `margin: 0 auto;` vc consegue alinha-los no centro novamente olha aqui https://prnt.sc/t6vk02 Qq dúvida comenta ai que te ajudo

Comment: Funcionou, você pode me falar apenas como dar uma margem entre os inputs?

Comment: @JeanExtreme002 olha ai https://prnt.sc/t72ffn

Comment: Muito obrigado ;)

Comment: @JeanExtreme002 de nada jovem!

Answer (score 0):

Poderia ser resolvido assim também.

Dependendo do que esta fazendo. Provavelmente precisará colocar um label.

Pra adicionar um label, ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```html
<body>
 <div>
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkBox[]" class="checkbox-block" id="checkbox-id-1">
  <label for="checkbox-id-1">Checkbox 1</label>
 </div>
 <div>
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkBox[]" class="checkbox-block" id="checkbox-id-2">
  <label for="checkbox-id-2">Checkbox 2</label>
 </div>
 <div>
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkBox[]" class="checkbox-block" id="checkbox-id-3">
  <label for="checkbox-id-3">Checkbox 3</label>
 </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pode utilizar uma div flexbox em forma de coluna e definir um `width` para os inputs (de forma geral ou individual). No exemplo abaixo defini um `width 200px` para a div onde estão os inputs. Como a div é um flexbox, os inputs terão 100% de largura da div:

```css
div.col{
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   width: 200px;
}

div.col input:not(:last-child){
   margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<p>
   Exemplo de inputs em coluna:
</p>
<div class="col">
   <input type="text">
   <input type="text">
   <input type="text">
   <input type="text">
</div>
```

Defini também um espaçamento de `10px` de um input ao outro abaixo, exceto no último com `:not(:last-child)`.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer de várias maneiras como já falado, você só deve decidir se o CSS será colocado no `input` (ou seja todos os input terão esse efeito) ou em alguma `.classeDefinida` (então vc especifica quando quer usar) no caso abaixo criei uma `.class` chamada `.limitar`

```css
.limitar{
     inline-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="limitar"> 
<input type="text">
<input type="text">
<input type="text">
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

tenta colocar no CSS, cada input, como Display: block; Ou então no container em que eles estão.

Answer (score -2):

```css
    *{
        padding: 0px;
        margin: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    body{
        width: 100vw;
        height: 100vh;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        background-color: #6A6F69;
    }
    .btn1{
        text-decoration: none;
        margin: 3px;
        width: 170px;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 10px;
        font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
        font-size: 23px;
        border-radius: 20px;
        display: flex;
        background-color: #4DDB34;
        color: white;
        box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 2px #4D4C4C;
    }
    .btn1:hover{
        box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 2px #1F1F1F;
    }
```

```html
<a href="https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2171764" class="btn1">Media Creation</a>
<a href="https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2156295" class="btn1">Midia De instalção</a>
<a href="https://software.download.prss.microsoft.com/dbazure/Win11_22H2_BrazilianPortuguese_x64v1.iso?t=1baf7604-3269-4ff1-879a-1fc7ada58837&e=1670228237&h=b72022398ef43a45c99d6bd08d31b404814231f53733ae7b2456afbcc2cb6f2d" class="btn1">Iso Windows MultiSelect</a>
```

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).